# How to get object id in after_filter during object creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

The following works for an `update`:

```
after_filter :only => [:create, :update] do
    logger.info params[:id]
end
```

**How can I reference the id on `create`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. There's no params[:id] because you don't have any record of that id, you only create it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
after_filter :only => [:create, :update] do
    logger.info params[:id].nil? ? self.id : params[:id]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
after_filter :only => [:create, :update] do
 logger.info (resource && resource.id) || params[:id]
end
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the id won't be in `params` for the create case.

You would have to (in the update & create methods) stash the created.updated record in a instance variable and refer to that instance variable in your after filter.

Answer (score 0):

you can set params[:id] in create action to object's id if it was successfully saved.

then it will exist in after_filter.